# Goerli ETH - Where get funds

Tags: contract-development, testing, goerli

I'm doing my computer engineering final degree work on Ethereum development. I am having a lot of problems to get GoerliETH, how do you guys get funding from testnets to develop your projects?

If someone can donate me some GoerliETH I would appreciate it very much, because at the moment I'm pretty stuck.

Address: 0x61f627aEde53cd928fB788AF7713d3212119dDC5

Comment: I'd recommend to try another testnet like sepolia.

Answer (score 1):

https://goerlifaucet.com/ works well, just set a reminder to check back once a day.